# iOS crash: library not loaded mremap_encrypted

Tags: ios, frameworks, crash

The app review team says my app always crash on launch, they gave me some crash logs, looks like this:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/RestKit.framework/RestKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EF2027CE-CEE4-4DB3-AC86-7AA3796FE67C/Udinn.app/Udinn
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EF2027CE-CEE4-4DB3-AC86-7AA3796FE67C/Udinn.app/Frameworks/RestKit.framework/RestKit: mremap_encrypted() => -1, errno=12 for /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EF2027CE-CEE4-4DB3-AC86-7AA3796FE67C/Udinn.app/Frameworks/RestKit.framework/RestKit
  Dyld Version: 370.1
```

This is dynamic link error, seems it's failed when load RestKit.framework(other logs are about other frameworks, like SwiftAddressbook, TransitionKit, but all with a same reason), I did see a lot people have a similar error with "mmap error 1", but not any one met the same error "mremap_encrypted" with me. The problem is I can't reproduce it, so I have no idea if upload a new binary could work. Any body has an idea what this means and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution? I cannot reproduct either in another project. I have been banging my head against the wall for two days

Comment: No, I have no idea what happened here. I was just recompile and submit a new binary to app store. And a few days later, they approved it. And I also asked help from Apple Developer Technical Support, they just replied "The issue you have reported appears to be resolved." and nothing else. I guess it may be something wrong on apple side. Remember the sha1/sha2 issue of mac app store? I met this error in the same period, it maybe just a coincidence, but who knows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the issue is a matter of running out of memory and iOS not really dealing with this in a great way and that the only reason your app was accepted when you resubmitted was because the (new) reviewer’s device was not in the same situation.

I did a write-up of the issue on our app’s repo: https://github.com/artsy/eigen/issues/1246

Comment: Saw this error when installing an app having a dylib inside a framework. I'm using `iPad5,1` with `iPhone OS 13.5.1`

Comment: Bug also reported in Apple's developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/41128?answerId=623292022