# Swift Binary rejected and i cannot reproduce the crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sdk

Apple just rejected my app because they claim it crashed on launch. 
Detailed crash logs  are :

```
Version:             143 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-12 16:10:55.55 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-01-12 16:10:54.54 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxx
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxx
xxx.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit: mremap_encrypted() => -1, errno=12 for /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxx
xxx.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/ xxx.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit: mremap_encrypted() => -1, errno=12 for /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
xxx.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
Dyld Version: 370.6
```

The app is written is swift and the problem is I cannot reproduce the crash on any device. I've tested on iphone 5, 6 and 6s Plus. Do you have an idea on what might have caused the problem, how i can reproduce the problem and how i can finally solve the problem is there is any? Some other thread here said that if you resubmit the app might be accepted, is this advice valid ? Thanks in advance for your answers

**EDIT 1**
I forgot to mention that the app got rejected in version 1.1 There was no rejection  at version 1.0

**EDIT 2**
I contacted apple developer support and their answer was not related to the FBSDKLoginKit framework

I am writing to you today in response to your inquiry about your App crashing.

After reviewing your case we have determined that you may be using Resource Rules in your project’s code signing settings. Resource Rules are no longer supported.  Please review your build settings in Xcode and remove any Resource Rules.

After removing any Resource Rules from your build settings, please clean your project by selecting the Clean command from the Project menu while holding down the option key.  This will delete any intermediate files from previous builds.  After that you should be able to build your project successfully.

The problem is that i never used resource rules.

Comment: without any code, it's impossible to help you

Comment: Unless you do not believe Apple you could expect users to also have the crash if it is released as-is. That would not be good.

Comment: Have you tested ad-hoc builds on clean (fully reset/erased) iPhones?

Comment: Is `FBSDKLoginKit.framework` added to Embedded Binaries in project settings?

Comment: FBSDKLoginKit.framework is part of the pods.framework that is created with cocoapods . I try to put the pods.framework it in the embedded binaries but i get an error when i try to upload to apple so i didn't include it in the  embedded binaries. Should i ?

Answer (score 0):

As I shared here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921044/95397:

> I *think* the issue is a matter of running out of memory and iOS not really dealing with this in a great way and that the only reason your app was accepted when you resubmitted was because the (new) reviewer’s device was not in the same situation.
>
> I did a write-up of the issue on our app’s repo: https://github.com/artsy/eigen/issues/1246